# Probability involving Union

Tags: probability

A problem in a book goes like this,

A restaurant serves a bowl of candies to their costumers. The bowl of candies Gabriel receives has 10 chocolate candies, 8 coffee candies, and 12 caramel candies. After gabriel chooses a candy,he eats it. Find the probability of getting candies with the indicated flavors.

a. P(chocolate or coffee)
b. P(caramel or not coffee)
c. P(coffee or caramel)
d. P(chocolate or not caramel)

In the problem d. P(chocolate or not caramel), I'm able to get $18/30$ or $0.6$ or $60\%$, i.e.

$P($chocolate or not caramel$)=P($chocolate$)+P($not caramel/coffee$)$
$P($chocolate or not caramel$)=10/30+8/30$
$P($chocolate or not caramel$)=18/30$

However, when I look in the book's answer key the answer is 9/10.

What part do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the book is wrong. Since "chocolate" is a subset of "not caramel", $P($chocolate or not caramel$)=P($not caramel$)=18/30=3/5$, as you got.

$9/10$ is what you would get from adding the two probabilities (for "chocolate" and for "not caramel") together. But that is definitely the wrong thing to do.